# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, amazon-s3, amazon-lambda

I have an `mlflow` server that is hosted on `aws`, that uses `s3` in the background for storage. I am trying to run a `lambda-function` that runs a python script which accesses the `mlflow` server, loads a `pytorch` model, makes predictions and finishes. The code where my problems arise is:

```
with open('./data/api_keys.json', 'r') as f:
    API_KEYS = json.load(f)

os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = API_KEYS['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = API_KEYS['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = API_KEYS['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

mlflow.set_tracking_uri(MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI)

model = mlflow.pytorch.load_model(MODEL_URI)     # <---- error thrown here
```

The traceback from `cloudwatch` is:

```
File "/app/production_script.py", line 26, in <module>
model = mlflow.pytorch.load_model(MODEL_URI)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/pytorch/__init__.py", line 693, in load_model
local_model_path = _download_artifact_from_uri(artifact_uri=model_uri)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/artifact_utils.py", line 95, in _download_artifact_from_uri
return get_artifact_repository(artifact_uri=root_uri).download_artifacts(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repo.py", line 179, in download_artifacts
if self._is_directory(artifact_path):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repo.py", line 61, in _is_directory
listing = self.list_artifacts(artifact_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/s3_artifact_repo.py", line 121, in list_artifacts
for result in results:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 269, in __iter__
response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 357, in _make_request
return self._method(**current_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 960, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
```

As per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html), `ListObjectsV2`

> Returns some or all (up to 1,000) of the objects in a bucket with each request.

> To use this operation, you must have READ access to the bucket.

> To use this action in an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policy, you must have >permissions to perform the s3:ListBucket action.

In my `policy` that I've defined for this `lambda-function`, I have `s3:ListBucket` permission for the bucket that `mlflow` is hosted on.

Any ideas on how to fix this are welcome.